STM32F407 using advanced timer TIM1 in output compare
I have been unsuccessful in using TIM1 as an Output Compare timer to output a regular pulse signal (PWM is not needed). I was trying to migrate the code that works for other timers but I cannot get it to work with TIM1. I saw that to use advanced timers you have to set the TIMx_BDTR.MOE bit. I have tried this but am still not seeing the Output Compare as expected.
void TIMER1_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim1OC_init;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_init;

    // Enable the TIM1 clock
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();

    // Enable the GPIO clock for TIM1 channel pin (e.g., PA8 for TIM1_CH1)
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    // Configure GPIO pin for TIM1_CH1
    gpio_init.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    gpio_init.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    gpio_init.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    gpio_init.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    gpio_init.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio_init);

    // Required bit setting for advanced timers
    TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E_Msk;
    TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;
    TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

    // Initialize TIM1 base
    htimer1.Instance = TIM1;
    htimer1.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    htimer1.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    // Configure Output Compare mode for TIM1_CH1
    tim1OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim1OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim1OC_init.Pulse = pulse[4];

    if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer1, &tim1OC_init, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

Note: I am using function HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK with interrupt handler TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void) and NVIC settings
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_CC_IRQn,15,0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_CC_IRQn);


Ah, the advanced timers. Had some major headbanging with them when trying to generate very precise and very fast signals...
Anyway, .... MOE is the highest bit... TIM1->BDTR |= 1<<15. HAL should've set it up on channel enable, so I guess you are not using it to actually start the timer.

Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately changing the code didn't work. I'm struggling to find any code online that shows how to use an advanced timer as an output compare mode

That you have should do I think. I assume you've got your pin alternative function set, GPIO port clock enabled and all that? Basically after the TIMER1_Init() you should only need 3 things to run it: CC1E bit set, MOE bit set, and CEN bit set. Check TIM1 registers in debugger while it is running: is it actually running, did OC triggered (CC1IF flag), is MOE/CC1E still set? Also I've noticed your period is 2^32; TIM1 is a 16-bit timer so you'll get 2^16 period instead (and compare value will be truncated the same).

Yes I do have the AF set and GPIO port enabled, I edited the code to show that stuff in TIMER1_Init(). I will work on confirming the CC1E and CEN bit is set and then go into the debugger and check.

@AndreyTurkin I added
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E_Msk;
TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;
TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
to set the bits and confirmed that they stay set throughout the operation. Furthermore during debugging I confirmed that the interrupt handler is working and is being called.
void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void)
{
HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htimer1);
}
The next step I guess would be to try different interrupt handlers from the vector table. Really confused why I can't see the output since everything appears to be working.

So your timer is working, compare event triggers, both CC1E and MOE are set. You don't even need to set them up manually if you are using HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT since it does all that for you. GPIO settings look fine also.
This is puzzling. Please zero-init your local struct variables and also check if OC1CE bit is low? Apart from that, I don't see what else could be wrong. If nothing else helps, put your code aside for a moment and make the most basic PWM example application you can do using TIM1. Who knows, maybe there is an actual hardware issue?

@AndreyTurkin I found a workaround that will do for the time being. If I don't use the AF mode and initialize the pin as a regular GPIO and then in HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback() simply use HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8); it works. Although this seems definitely suboptimal, might be a hardware issue, will check with a different board.

Swapped out discovery boards and same behavior, strange, oh well

Bitbanging is definitely suboptimal. If you want to get to the bottom of this, I'd suggest starting with a known-working example (timer PWM is one of the go-to examples for stm I think). Make sure it works, then try to figure out the difference. Either by merging the code bit by bit , or by comparing timer registers, or both.

I'll try to get around to it at some point. Currently I noticed that I have a bigger issue. TIM2/TIM5 work as expected but the other 6 timers just oscillate at a constant frequency regardless of what I set as the pulse. I'll create another post.

@AndreyTurkin Thank you for your help. I did a massive loop based on your last comment. I finally switched to using PWM instead of OC. This seemed to fix a few of my issues but the workaround no longer works for TIM1 since there is no interrupt. Do you know where I can find the example of getting TIM1 to work with PWM?

See e.g. https://controllerstech.com/pwm-in-stm32/ . It should really be that easy. As for your current code... I'd like to reiterate two points not sure if you addressed them. Firstly, make sure to zero-init your structures. Garbage left in non-initialized fields might give you troubles (you might also want to USE_FULL_ASSERT to make HAL validate all the parameters). Secondly, TIM1/8/3/4 are 16 bit timers, so 0xFFFFFFFF is not a realistic period. It shouldn't break everything in this way, but still better to address that.
